# alternate form $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}$

Tags: factoring

For a part of one of my prove for limits I have to show that $$\sqrt x -\sqrt c = \frac{x-c}{\sqrt x + \sqrt c}$$

I understand that $\sqrt x = \frac{x}{\sqrt x}$ but I can not figure out why $$ \frac{x}{\sqrt x} - \frac{c}{\sqrt c}  = \frac{x-c}{\sqrt x + \sqrt c}$$

If someone could explain how I can conclude that these two are the same that would be appreciated.

Comment: In your second line the $-$ in the denominator should be $+$

Comment: Note that $a-b=(a^2-b^2)/(a+b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the fraction
$$
\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt c}{1}
$$
and expand it by a factor of $\sqrt x+\sqrt c$. This doesn't change the value of the fraction, but it does change what it looks like.

Comment: It looks as if someone saw something anappropriate in our answers…

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The ways of the downvote fairies are ineffable.

Answer (score 1):

Because$$x-c=\sqrt x^2-\sqrt c^2=\left(\sqrt x+\sqrt c\right)\left(\sqrt x-\sqrt c\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt x -\sqrt c = (\sqrt x -\sqrt c)\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt c}{\sqrt x +\sqrt c}  =  \frac{(\sqrt x -\sqrt c)\cdot (\sqrt{x} + \sqrt c )}{\sqrt x +\sqrt c}\\ = \frac{\sqrt x \cdot \sqrt x - \sqrt c\cdot  \sqrt c }{\sqrt x +\sqrt c} =\frac{x-c}{\sqrt x + \sqrt c}$$